# The After hook in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

Folks,

I am having some trouble working with the `After`hook. I have organized my tests in folders like this:

```
features/Accounts/accounts_api.feature
features/Accounts/step_definition/account_steps.rb

features/labs/create_lab.feature
features/labs/step_definition/labs_steps.rb
```

Now I have an `After` hook present in the step definition of the Accounts feature, I want that hook to run after every scenario of the "Accounts" feature, but I do not want it to run after every scenario of the "labs" feature. I tried this:

`cucumber --tags @newlabs`

the above should run all the scenarios present in the labs feature tagged as `newlabs` but what I am seeing is that once the scenario tagged as`@newlabs` runs the `@after` hook present in the step definition of Accounts starts to run. I am thinking why is this happening, am I using the hook in the wrong way or is my overall understanding of hooks wrong?

Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks don't care what step definition script they're located in and will run for every scenario.  Or, more specifically, your after hook will run after every scenario that runs, for every feature, regardless of the tags you pass in to Cucumber.

If you want a little more control over that, check out the [Cucumber wiki page on hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) and look in the section called 'Tagged hooks'.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you define `After` hook in wrong place. Note that `After` hook (as well as other hooks) must be defined in the `.rb`, not in the `.feature` file. Common place for hooks is `features/support/hooks.rb`. You will define your hook this way:

```
# features/support/hooks.rb
After('@newlabs') do # will run after each scenario tagged with @newlabs 
   # your teardown ruby code 
end

# features/Accounts/accounts_api.feature
@newlabs # tag all scenarious of this feature with @newlabs tag
Feature: your feature

Scenario: your scenario
  Given: ...
  When: ...
  Then: ...
```

In cucumber output you won't see that `After` hook is executed (unless you output something to `STDOUT` from the hook definition) - [hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) will run implicitly.